# Hover menu inside a tablecell, having z-index issues

Tags: css, z-index, css-tables

Have a hover menu inside a table cell (td) and have the td set to `position:relative`, the menu set to `position:absolute`, and as you see the menu renders behind the border and text below:

[image]

Comment: What did you set the z-index to? Also set the background-color property of the menu element to something (maybe white etc) and see if it works

Comment: @Cybernate - Doesn't seem like a background problem - see the number 0 overlapping the menu's border and content.

Comment: @Myles: Correct. Didn't notice that 0 was overlapping the border.

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a `z-index` issue, set your `table` to a `z-index:0;` in CSS and the menu to `z-index:999;`

See: http://tjkdesign.com/articles/z-index/teach_yourself_how_elements_stack.asp for further info.